# C++: How can I find a specific character in a string with an if? What is the "==" equivalent for strings, if there is one?

Tags: c++

For example, I want to detect a negative in a string. I am not sure if converting the char into a const char* would work (and because doing so would be a pain because then I would not know how it would affect the rest of my code. Is there a way I can check if for any value of input[i], it "equals" a dash/negative?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define LOG(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
char solveBIG(std::string input) {
     for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i += 2) {    
            if (input[i] = "-") {
            //
            }
     }

}
int main() {
    std::string example1 = {"1 2 3 - 5"};
    LOG(solveBIG(example1))
}
```

Comment: `input[i]` is a character, not a string. Try `input[i] == '-'`. Note the single quotes and the double equal sign.

Comment: You can also use `if ( input.find_first_of('-') != std::string::npos)` . Look for all std::string operations here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string. I always try to write code with as little (visible) loops as possible and use code that describes more what the code does then how it does it. (And the word `find` does that)

Comment: @PepijnKramer `string::find_first_of()` is overkill for searching for a single character, use `string::find()` instead.

Comment: Tip: Avoid `#define` in C++. Use `const`. Use functions that the compiler will inline.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful with distinguishing operators `=` and `==`. The first is the [assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) operator, and the second is the [comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) operator for equality.

You mixed that up a little bit.

Now, how to detect a `'-'` in the string?

Solution: You will iterate over the string and compare each charcter in the string with the `'-'` character'.

More explanations:

In many many programming languages, so called ***loop***s are used to execute or repeat blocks of code.

Or do ***iterate*** over "something". Therefore loops are also called ***Iteration statements***

Also C++ has *loops* or *iteration statements*. The basic loop constructs are

- [for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for),
- [while loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while),
- [do-while loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)
- [Range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Please click on the links and read the descriptions in the C++ reference. You can use any of them to solve your problem.

---

Additionally, you need to know that a `string` is a ***container***. *Container* means that a variable of such a type ***contains*** other elements from nearly any type.

A `string` for example, contains characters.

Example: If you have a string equivalent to `"Hello"`, then it contains the characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`.

Another nice property of some containers is, that they have an *index* operator, or better said, a ***subscript*** operator `[]`. So, if you want to access a character in your string, you may simply use your variable name with an index specified in the subscript operator.

**Very important**:  Indices in C++ start with 0. So the first character in a `string` is at index 0. Example:

```
std::string test = "Hello";
std::cout << test[0];
```

will print `H`.

With all the above gained know how, we can now solve your problem easily. We will iterate over all characters in your string, and then check if each character is `'-'` or not.

One of many many possible implementations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {    
    if (input[i] == '-') {
        //
    }
}
```